Drawing content over status and navigation bars in android
How can I display my content over the status and navigation bars in Android 11 (API 30)??
I've used:

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

works on every android version I try aside from Android 11, so how do I make it work on andorid 11?
My goal is to make the navigation and status bars transparent so that my content where the bars would appear.

You cannot make content "appear over" the status / nav bars. That would allow apps to prevent the user from pressing back / home / recents which is a no-no. If you want want the content to "appear behind" the status / nav bars and make them transparent for a full-screen effect, have you looked at the edge-to-edge documentation?
